# How to perform Parallel DataBinding in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a collection class. Say CellCollection, which contains Cells which contains a collection called Cell.

[image]

If we do data binding it binds in linear manner. Like first cell11, cell12, cell13, cell14 then, cell21, cell22, etc.,

[Lets assume the collection size is static and proceed]
I have an ItemTemplate for ListBox, which consists of StackPanel which contains 3 textblocks. What I want is the first textblock to have first `"Cells"`'s first cell ie, `Cell11`, followed by the second textblock to have second `"Cells"`'s first cell `Cell21` etc.,

Is it possible to bind the collections using indexes in such a way they will be processes in-parallel.

I dono't how to ask this question. I hope the image would help.

Comment: Can't you do it the other way around? I mean, a ListBox that layout inner ListBoxs vertically, that in turn layout cells horizontally?

Comment: In real time, I'll have around 20k items. So, 20K instance of ListBoxes are entirely wrong. Anyway. I've solved this problem. By creating a SingleTon class with a property of the type CellCollection. Then, sent Cell count as ItemsSource and passed index of cells as parameter and bound the values to textboxes. Entire thing is fine. Entire process completes in less than 1s for 20K. But, I had to use converter and Have to create DataTemplate Dynamically. Thanks for the suggesstion :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've create dynamic xaml using xaml reader and assigned it as template for the list box. Everything is fine now :)